# My Project is not recognizing the added project

Tags: android

```
<com.mobidevelop.widget.SplitPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:spl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    spl:orientation="vertical"
    spl:splitterSize="12dip"
    spl:splitterPosition="33%"
    spl:splitterBackground="@drawable/splitter_bg_v"
    >
```

I am trying to develop an application on SplitPane concepts in android.

I downloaded the application from github
        https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout

when I imported the project,I am getting the following error in the main.xml file at the line which I mentioned above

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'splitterSize' in package 'com.mobidevelop.widget'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'splitterPosition' in package 
     'com.mobidevelop.widget'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'com.mobidevelop.widget'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'splitterBackground' in package 
     'com.mobidevelop.widget'
```

Please help to solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing this file:

https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout/blob/master/split-pane-layout/res/values/attrs.xml

Either that, or do `Project > Clean` to make sure the R file regenerates itself.